# Is it feasible to buy a small boat in Leticia, Colombia and travel down the Amazon?

Tags: adventure, extreme-tourism, riverboats, amazon-river

Boating the length of the Amazon is a big dream but it just occurred to me that it might not be that difficult. There is a public passenger boat that travels from Leticia to Manaus in four days. That is half the entire distance to the sea. While the cost of a voyage on this boat is reasonable (I've heard about US$100) it doesn't seem the most pleasant way to travel (24/7 in a hammock watching people drink beer all day and throw the cans overboard).

Instead, I would like to buy a small river boat in Leticia, and with a few friends, spend a month or more traveling slowly down the river, stopping in the towns and settlements along the way making rest stops, refueling, buying supplies and water, and continuing.

The total distance is [about 3000km](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zH14Qa949zgI.khMSD-DTigwc):

[image: map of the amazon]

What does one need to consider for such a journey?

Comment: You're going to have to reduce the number of questions in the post - remember ([help]), generally one question per post, unless highly related.  At present it's likely to be closed as too broad or unclear.

Comment: As an aside, I've been eyeing up that route for about 5 years now, really really want to return to South America to do it (although I was looking at going from Manaus to Leticia on that public boat).  Just do it, don't worry about security concerns, if the public does it every day and they're ok, you will be too.  (see the book 'Lunatic Express' as evidence of this).

Comment: Also 'are x a concern' is kinda subjective, which may also get the question closed.  Some people don't care about those things (eg 'is the plane crashing a concern') while others won't fly on any airline with a plane crash in its history.  Similarly, the Crocodile Hunter had no issues chasing crocs and snakes, while you or I may run in the other direction.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's super broad. But there really is only one question: Is it feasible to buy a small boat in Leticia and travel down the Amazon? The sub-questions are points that must be considered to decide if it is feasible.

Comment: Movies don't seem to paint an encouraging picture of what happens when you go boating on the Amazon.  You thought of *Mosquito Coast*; I immediately thought of [*Aguirre, the Wrath of God*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aguirre,_the_Wrath_of_God).

Comment: The mobile coverage map provided by opensignal.com indicates locations where _users of opensignal have been before that had signal_. If there is a dead zone, that might just be because nobody with a smartphone has been there before. This is, however a great way to find settlements, and it's encouraging to see plenty of communities with signals along the way.

Comment: @pnuts, I'm not sure opensignal is widely used around here, but every carrier must publish their cell phone coverage. I suggest you try the websites of the main carriers like TIM (http://portasabertas.tim.com.br/?_ga=1.232488863.1059667145.1421670923), Claro (http://www.claro.com.br/celular/cobertura/) and Vivo (http://www.vivo.com.br/portalweb/appmanager/env/web?_nfls=false&_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vivoVcCoberturaRoamingBook&WT.ac=portal.movel.coberturaeroaming#).

Comment: I have actually completed the section of this journey between Leticia and Manaus, and I can provide answers to all of my own questions. Would anyone be able to re-open this question? I think the information will be very useful to anyone planning to travel on the Amazon. @MarkMayo

Comment: @QuinnComendant the problem is it's got too many questions in it, which is against the [help] rules :(  If you can edit to meet the rules, I'd be happy to reopen, it sounds amazing!

Comment: @MarkMayo I've edited to meet the rule (I hope). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get out your computer and head for Google's satellite maps and work your way downstream.  You can literally see where towns of any size are and their names.  Then try doing some searches on what may be in that town. This will help you answer for yourself several of the questions you asked.

Call the Brazilian Embassy in Colombia and ask what the rules are on crossing the border with a boat you bought in Colombia.  They will know better than anyone here.

Assuming you can get good answers from these first two steps, then ask yourself / your companions ... can you read the river, can you fix a boat's motor by yourself, do you love mosquitoes.

Comment: Why the down votes ... it is valid advice.

Comment: Hi Tom, I didn't downvote you, but I'm guessing someone did because you didn't specifically answer the question, just alluded to how the answer could be found. But it's  valid advice anyways. =)